# What does "a." mean in this snippet of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the Javascript below, what does the `a.` before the `cell1` signify?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("a.cell1").click(function(){
```

---

EDIT:  Thanks for the answers.  Would it work if I did this to the Facebook Like button:

```
<fb:like href=""  class="cell1" send="true" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Comment: `'a.cell1'` is a CSS selector. The specification is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: you sould've made that an answer and you could have gotten the pointzzz1

Answer (score 5):

It means an `A` tag with a `cell1` class:

```
 <A href="..." class="cell1">text</a>
```

will be matched

Comment: Thanks... will it work with Facebook Like button as I ask above?

Comment: I don't think so; I don't think the facebook tag is a real HTML tag. It will be converted into HTML when it's displayed (I assume). You also can't use that syntax unless you include the jQuery script in your page.

Comment: fb:like tags are converted indeed to A tags by the facebook js library, you should inspect what classes are unique to this links, something like `connect_widget_like_button`

Comment: @RMorrisey: I have `<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.pack.js'></script>` at the top of the page?  Would it work then?

Comment: @Variant: Any idea where I could find what CSS class to use with a Facebook Like button?

Comment: @John: Firebug is your friend

Answer (score 3):

`$('a.cell1')` is a jQuery selector; it acts the same way that css selectors do. `a.` doesn't mean anything in JavaScript. In this context, though, it's getting a `<a>` with the class `cell1`.

Comment: Actually, it's getting an `<a>` with the class `cell1`. The `.` specifies that `cell1` is a class selector, just as `#` specifies an id selector. Without any of these prefixes you're matching a tag name. But your answer is intentionally correct.

Answer (score 0):

The script you showed uses a third-party javascript library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The syntax: `$('blah')` is used to pick out all DOM elements matching the CSS selector `blah`. In this case, the code is selecting all elements like `<a class="cell1".../>`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it selects `a` elements with a class of `cell1`.

To your added question about Facebook, you might need to use [jQuery's `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the click event to it, since Facebook adds the `a` element after page load.

If `.click()` doesn't work, try [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: thanks I'll look into that if "click" doesn't work.  Any idea if I can add my own CSS class to the Facebook Like button?

Comment: @John I'm not sure. It looks like Facebook uses some generic classes that you may be able to exploit.